# Transferring from CDG airport to hotel in Paris, France preferably by train

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, cdg

How can I get from CDG airport to Hotel du Cadran, 10 Rue du Champ de Mars, 75007 Paris, France, with minimum number of transfers?  I do have luggage to carry.  I prefer to travel by train, if possible.

Comment: When you want to know how to get from A to B, it's much faster to go to Google Maps than to ask a question on a website and hope somebody answers.

Answer (score 0):

Most itineraries returned by google maps will have you take a bus from the last RER (train) stop in Paris  (RER B station Saint-Michel Notre-Dame).

One itinerary suggests taking the "Le Bus Direct Ligne 2" from CGG to Champs-Elysée-Étoile, then the city bus line 92 that will drop you 50 meters from your hotel. (https://goo.gl/maps/E6YB7p4XpRC2)

The "Le Bus Direct  Ligne 2" final stop is at the Eiffel tower (18-20 rue Jean Rey ), but it is on the other side of the tower, so will force you to walk more to your hotel (15 minutes walk)

Good luck.